# Moving lips during Salah without sound

Tags: salat, fiqh, mistake

Asalamualikum
I prayed maghrib in congregation and was **repeating** a lot of what I said over and over again, because I didn’t properly hear it or felt like I didn’t pronounce **a word/verse** properly. And then in the last rakat I got frustrated and prayed it without any sound but made sure I **moved** my lips .Is my prayer invalid ?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please explain what you mean to say? If you pray in a congregation you must follow the imam this mean that the recitation of the imam is sufficient (except for the case of al-Fatihah according some madhhabs). And therefore as long as you follow the imam you must pray silently and not raise your voice.

Comment: Congregational prayer is supposed to be prayed at low voice, at the limit moving the lips without a voice is ok. We are not praying to our neighbours but to God, and He will hear what we think.

The question is rather whether the prayer is valid when you get frustrated during prayer. Is it about that you are asking?